# How to search for h264 files on SD card recovered with PhotoRec

Tags: ubuntu, data-transfer, vlc-media-player

An ext 4 formatted SD card that I used to record videos was recently corrupted, and I had to use PhotoRec to pull data off the card.  After doing this, I was able to track down log files that showed my video files had been successfully written when the pi was operational, e. g.:

```
2015-09-07T13:08:36.000Z        34.49127333     -104.21763833   1270.80 34.166  /home/pi/hasp_videos/2015-09-07T13-08-36p000Z_34p49127333_-104p21763833_1270p80.h264
```

So they should be somewhere on the SD card, and by extension, in the recovered data.  However, since PhotoRec cannot resurrect file names, and did not rename any of the recovery files with the ".h264" suffix, I'm left with two possibilities:

1. The video files are in the recovery drive, with unknown names and unknown suffixes.
2. PhotoRec did not recover them

Being an optimist, I'm trying to figure out how to identify which of the 100,000+ recovered files are my video files.  My first thought was to try and use VLC player to play any file above 1 Mb in size:

```
find * -size +1M | `sed 's/^/vlc /'`
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Or is #2 right and I never recovered the videos in the first place?